# How to upload a local file as link in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I want to know how to add a local file path as a link and after adding it i want to download the file while clicking the link in asp.net.

My code:

```
<a href="D:/Sample/test.html" runat="server">
```

Here i just add my local path to the server.But here nothing done while clicking the link. I want to use .zip file instead of .html file.Let me know how to upload and download by using a link.Thanks in advance

Comment: put files in your project eg : Doc/File1.txt 
then <a href="doc/File1.txt" runat="server">

Comment: its not working even the file is in my project folder

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by local file path? A path on the server itself or client. Or are you trying to reference a file on your computer with a link on the server? As @Aamir points out you need a relative path.

Comment: have a look => [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @VDWWD Yes, am trying to upload a file in my computer with a link on the server

Comment: @MSDP that is not possible without uploading the file to the server first.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the problem here. Just add "`~/`" to find file from the root of your project and add `runat="server"` to the anchor link:

```
<a href="~/document.zip" runat="server">Download Zip File</a>
```

You need to resolve it from the root because while you may know that it's on the D drive on your local machine, you cannot be sure that will be the same on the server. And even if it is on the same drive on the server, what if someone migrates it later on?

As for uploading a file, simply use the [Upload control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227669.aspx)?

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of situation, Using this code you can do it.

File Upload Code

```
string FilePath = "";
string[] a = new string[1];
string fileName = "";
string FullName = "";

if (FileUploader.FileName.Length > 0)
{
     a = FileUploader.FileName.Split('.');
     fileName = Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks) + "." + a.GetValue(1).ToString();
     FilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\SavedFolder");
     Fup1.SaveAs(FilePath + @"\" + fileName);

     FullName = FilePath + @"\" + fileName;
     // Database Saved Code
}
```

File Download Code

```
string filename = "filename from Database";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
string aaa = Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/" + filename);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/" + filename));
Response.End();
```